# how to filter deployed applications from weblogic rest api

Tags: json, rest, weblogic12c

I am trying to get list of deployed applications on weblogic server 12C. I am invoking curl command like : curl -u user:password http://host:port//management/wls/latest/deployments, and I get below result. My requirement is to exclude myapp form the search, and need result for only myapp2. I tried excludeFields=myapp.rar filter, but it did not work. any clues and help on this will be highly appreciated.

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "targets": ["1-Cluster"],
            "deploymentPath": "path",
            "name": "myapp.rar",
            "state": "active",
            "type": "application",
            "displayName": "myapp.rar"
        },
        {
            "targets": ["Server1-MS1"],
            "deploymentPath": "path",
            "name": "myapp2.rar",
            "state": "active",
            "type": "application",
            "displayName": "myapp2.rar"
        },
        {
            "targets": ["Server2-MS2"],
            "deploymentPath": "path",
            "name": "myapp2.rar",
            "state": "active",
            "type": "application",
            "displayName": "myapp2.rar"
        },
        ]

}
```

Comment: excludeFields is used to filter on attribute names (name, state, type, etc...) and not on attribute values. The REST API does not provide any filter on values.